# Changing time or offsetting it in OpenVZ contained server

Tags: linux, debian, time, openvz

I am trying to run a VPS, a Debian box contained in an OpenVZ container. Obviously, I cannot use `time --set` or any such command, as the time must be set via the parent node. The owner of the parent node, however refuses to adjust the time (which is 30 minutes slower than the actual time).

All the programs on my system, consequently, now recognized the false time and this throws a wrench in my syncing. Is there a way to possibly change the system time without interference from the container's administrator? Or perhaps, failing that, a way to make the programs "see" the time 30 minutes faster than what is reported by the container?

Comment: Are you trying to do rsync?

Comment: among other things. biggest problem is that I've installed owncloud and now it fails to sync my data, because of the time difference.

Answer (score 0):

If the time difference is accurate and stable at 30min, you can try switching the timezone within your vps. I actually suspect the time difference you are seeing is due to timezone.

The following link has detail info on this

http://trulymanaged.com/blog/tag/change-time-zone-on-linux-vps/

Comment: Okay, the time being reported by the server is an accurate description of IRST time (Asia/Tehran), however the timezone is MSK. I want to see the same date and time, but have IRST as the timezone. When I do as suggested in the linked article I get the wrong date and time, but the correct timezone.

Comment: In that case, pick a timezone that is 30min faster to compensate that.

Comment: Changing the timezone only sets the user-visible time, it doesn't stop the wrong UTC time from screwing things up.